# Web3js events "fromBlock: 0" doesnt work

Tags: web3js, quorum, web3js-v1.x

I want to get events from block X. 
I have:

```
quorum-v2.4.0
web3js 1.2.6
```

And I have my own smart contracts I want to listen for. So I have created listener for allEvents like this:

```
  const event = contract.events.allEvents({
    fromBlock: 0,
  });
```

And I also have following snippet of code where I am listening for the new events and also for **the previous events**. So I am specifying  `fromBlock` as described in [web3js documentation](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.6/web3-eth-contract.html#contract-events):

> fromBlock - Number|String|BN|BigNumber (optional): The block number (greater than or equal to) from which to get events on. Pre-defined block numbers as "latest",

```
  event
    .on('data', console.log)
    .on('error', eventError);
```

When I dont specify `fromBlock: 0,` it doesnt return anything which is OK. When I set fromBlock to 0 it always return the last block (e.g block 6 - see below) even though  there are more blocks before the block number 6:

```
Object {address: "0x9d13C6D3aFE1721BEef56B55D303B09E021E27ab", blockNumber: 6, transactionHash: "0x51f254852cc897d6d3e40041b3a3e5dd7ec9a5ebddd771d9…", transactionIndex: 0, blockHash: "0x0eaec149917f0517aa99042875313882aa57831b3d02aaf5…", …}
```

Based on the documentation I assume it should return all events from block number 0. So I should get events in block 0,1,2,3,4...latest.

Do I understand it correctly?
Do I need to set some configuration? I want to workaround `contract.getPastEvents` and I want to set `fromBlock` within the subscription in listener.

Comment: It actually depends on which node you're using I believe. For example, infura doesn't throw an exception on block 0, but alchemy does. Just set `fromBlock` to 1.

Comment: @goodvibration Thanks a lot for your comment. I tried set it to different numbers. If the latest number is smaller than `fromBlock` it doesnt return any event. However when I set `fromBlock` to something smaller than current `latest` block (let's say 10) it always return the previous one (in this example block 9). I also tried converting to hex with `web3.utils.toHex(<fromBlock>)` but it didnt help as well

Comment: Have you tried using a callback function with `contract.events.allEvents`?

Comment: @sfmiller940 yes. didnt work... looks like there is a bug with connection in `websocket` provider for subscription in general. More details here https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/issues/3389

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/issues/3389 it turned out it was a bug. Fixed in `web3 1.2.7`

Answer (score 0):

Currently, I am using web3 version `1.2.1`, the below code is working for me. Please give `toBlock` as `latest`. So that web3 js will give you all the events for that range.

```
contract.getPastEvents('allEvents', {
    fromBlock: 0,
    toBlock: 'latest'
})
```

Comment: Thanks. The `getPastEvents` works fine, but I dont want to use second web3 call with `getPastEvents`. What I want is to create the subscription with `contract.events.allEvents` and within this subscription I want to get the previous transactions as stated in documentation with `fromBlock`